# Java Lambda for break inside two for loops

Tags: java, collections, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I am trying to convert an iterative block of code in Java 8 to functional. The functional approach is unable to find the matching message in the set shared.

```
List<Optional<Message>> allMessages = new ArrayList<>();

Set<Status> allStatuses = getAllStatuses();

//Iterative : Working
Set<StatusMessage> set = new HashSet<>(STATUS_MESSAGE.values());
for (StatusMessage statusMessage : set) {
    for (Status status : statusMessage.getStatusAndInfo().keySet()) {
        Optional<Message> message = MessageBuilder.createMessage(allStatuses, status, this::createMessage);
        if (message.isPresent()) {
            allMessages.add(message);
            break;
        }
    }
}

//Functional : Not working  - Never adds anything to the 
//map even when matching status is present
STATUS_MESSAGE.values().stream()
        .distinct()
        .map(statusMessage -> statusMessage.getStatusAndInfo().keySet())
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(key -> MessageBuilder.createMessage(allStatuses, key, this::createMessage))
        .anyMatch(allMessages::add);
```

The `MessageBuilder.createMessage` looks like this:

```
Optional<Status> matchingStatus = statuses.stream()
                .filter(matchingStatus::equals)
                .findFirst();
System.out.println("Found : " + matchingStatus.toString());
return matchingStatus.flatMap(creator);
```

Also, for debugging purposes, how can I see what is happening at each step of the stream? The stack in the debugger in intellij wasn't showing anything in the stream.

Comment: `anyMatch` expects a predicate and returns a boolean. You probably want `.filter()` and then just `.collect`

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working' ? Please detail

Comment: `.anyMatch(allMessages::add);` will stop as soon as it successfully adds, which will happen at the first iteration. Use `findFirst` instead (or findAny if the order is not relevant, and then write `allMessages = ...stream()...flatMap()..filter(Optional::isPresent).findFirst().orElse(emptyList());`

Comment: @VLAZ no, because of the `break`, a `find*` is more appropriate.

Comment: @njzk2 but the `break` is only for the inner loop and you should still continue with the outer...which then re-runs the inner. So, it's one item per outer loop (at most).

Comment: @VLAZ that is correct. Currently the functional approach is never able to find the status and adds nothing to the list `allMessages`

Comment: Why is the `.distinct()` on there? Is `STATUS_MESSAGE` an enum? How can it have duplicate values?

Comment: STATUS_MESSAGE is a Map<Status, StatusMessage>. The naming I have used can definitely be improved.

Comment: @tanvi What is the reason in storing messages in `List<Optional<Message>>`? Why not `List<Message>` instead? Is this enforced somehow by a framework / library ?

Comment: @ETO There are a lot of classes that return such Optional and the framework is then making decisions based on this information.

Comment: @VLAZ good point, I missed that part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
STATUS_MESSAGE.values().stream()
        .distinct()
        .forEach(statusMessage ->
            statusMessage.getStatusAndInfo().keySet().stream()
                    .map(status -> MessageBuilder.createMessage(allStatuses, status, this::createMessage))
                    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                    .findFirst()
                    .ifPresent(allMessages::add)
        );
```

---

**UPDATE**

To build the result list using `toList` instead of adding to a list:

```
List<Optional<Message>> allMessages = STATUS_MESSAGE.values().stream()
        .distinct()
        .flatMap(statusMessage ->
            statusMessage.getStatusAndInfo().keySet().stream()
                    .map(status -> MessageBuilder.createMessage(allStatuses, status, this::createMessage))
                    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                    .limit(1)
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: forEach should not be used to add things to a list. that's what collect is for (even though in that case it means a sligthly more complicated map in the middle

Comment: @njzk2 Added solution for that.

Comment: nice use of `limit`, I didn't think of using that in this case

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment, but it's too long...

---

Seems like your `MessageBuilder.createMessage` method is overcomplicated.

Check below a simplified and more readable version of the same logic:

```
if (allStatuses.contains(status)) {
    System.out.println("Found : " + status.toString());
    return creator.apply(status);
}
return Optional.empty();
```

Comment: I had optimised and moved a couple of object initiations away from this and never realised how simple this has become. Thanks for the note @ETO

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `forEach` for accumulating operations, so this should be more idiomatic:

```
Function<StatusInfo, Optional<Message>> messageForStatus = statusInfo -> 
        statusInfo().keySet().stream()
                    .map(status -> MessageBuilder.createMessage(allStatuses, status, this::createMessage))
                    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(Optional.empty());

allMessages = STATUS_MESSAGE.values().stream()
        .distinct()
        .map(StatusMessage::getStatusAndInfo)
        .map(messageForStatus)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .collect(toList());
```

As a side note, you have too many optionals, you may want to consider unwrapping some earlier, as a list of optionals may just as well be the list of only the present values.